# Arreglo en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tengo dos tablas relacionadas, ***movimiento*** y ***detalles_movimiento***:

```
movimiento
+---------------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field               | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+---------------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| codigo_movimiento   | int(10)   | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| tipo_movimiento     | char(15)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| tipo                | char(15)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| id_proveedor        | int(10)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| codigo_departamento | int(10)   | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| fecha_movimiento    | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
| id_usuario          | int(10)   | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |
| status_movimiento   | char(15)  | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
+---------------------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+

detalles_movimiento
+---------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| codigo_movimiento   | int(10)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| codigo_insumo       | int(10)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| cantidad_movimiento | int(10)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| status_movimiento   | char(15) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Tengo que obtener para un reporte el insumo que tuvo más salidas en un determinado tiempo.

Para resolverlo he usado esta consulta:

```
SELECT codigo_insumo, cantidad_movimiento FROM movimiento JOIN detalle_movimiento on movimiento.codigo_movimiento=detalle_movimiento.codigo_movimiento WHERE movimiento.fecha_movimiento BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-18 23:59:59' AND tipo_movimiento='SALIDA';
```

... y me arroja estos resultados:

```
+---------------+---------------------+
| codigo_insumo | cantidad_movimiento |
+---------------+---------------------+
|             2 |                   3 |
|             4 |                   5 |
|             3 |                   2 |
|             4 |                   4 |
|             2 |                   5 |
|             3 |                   5 |
|             4 |                   4 |
|             3 |                   7 |
|             2 |                   2 |
+---------------+---------------------+
```

Ahora he intentado transformar ese arreglo en un nuevo arreglo donde sume todos los movimientos de un mismo insumo, así obtengo los insumos con más salidas.

He intentado un montón de cosas y pues no se me da, quisiera saber si hay una mejor forma de obtener lo que quiero o si voy bien, como hacer lo del arreglo.

Comment: He colocado tambien php porque no solo necesito la consulta, tambien necesito convertir el arreglo en otro que me sume las cantidades para luego mostrar los insumos con mayor movimiento..

Comment: si no lo entiendo mal lo que quieres es el `maximo` agrupado por `insumo`?

Comment: La suma de todas las cantidades de entrada por insumo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    codigo_insumo, 
    SUM(cantidad_movimiento) 
FROM 
    movimiento 
    JOIN detalle_movimiento 
        on movimiento.codigo_movimiento=detalle_movimiento.codigo_movimiento 
WHERE 
    movimiento.fecha_movimiento BETWEEN '2016-11-01' AND '2016-11-18 23:59:59' 
    AND tipo_movimiento='SALIDA'
GROUP BY
    codigo_insumo;
```

si solo te interesa el mayor, tienes que añadir

```
ORDER BY SUM(cantidad_movimento)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Me trae solo la cantidad de movimiento maxima de los insumos, pero necesito la suma de todas las cantidades

Comment: Si, lo tienes que cambiar por sum

Comment: De verdad, gracias, estuve tan cerca pero a la vez tan lejos jajajaja 
Gracias :)